# How to limit choices on the Django filter based on the request.user

Tags: django, django-filters

I have a multi company setup. The user is logged into to a specific company. Every company has its own set of ledger accounts and transactions. On the transaction list I created filter options so that the user can filter based on "Description", "Transaction date" and "Ledger account". The problem with the Ledger Account is that the choices available is the accounts from all the companies. I ant to limit the choices to only show the Ledger Accounts from the current company that the user is logged into.

**User model**:

```
class custom_user(AbstractBaseUser):
    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    company_group           = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True)
    current_company         = models.ForeignKey(tcompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Note the current_company as a ForeignKey.

**Leger Account Model**:

```
class tledger_account(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False)
    gl_category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=category_choices, verbose_name='category', db_index=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, default=None)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(tcompany, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    class Meta:
        indexes =[
            models.Index(fields=['company', 'description'])
        ]
        unique_together = ['company', 'description']
```

Note the company as a ForeignKey.

**Views.py**:

```
class TransactionlistView(ListView):
    model = ttransactions
    template_name = 'accounting/transaction_list.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(TransactionlistView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TransactionlistView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        line_list = []
        context = {}
        balance = 0
        transactions = ttransactions.objects.order_by('transaction_date'). \
            filter(company=self.request.user.current_company)
        company = self.request.user.current_company

        transaction_count = transactions.count()
        myFilter = transactionFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=transactions, **kwargs)
        transactions = myFilter.qs
        transaction_lines_count = 0

        for transaction in transactions:
            transaction_lines = ttransaction_lines.objects.filter(transaction=transaction.id)

            transaction_lines_count = transaction_lines.count()
            mylineFilter = lineFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=transaction_lines)
            transaction_lines = mylineFilter.qs

            for transaction_line in transaction_lines:
                if transaction_line.transaction_type == 'Debit':
                    balance += transaction_line.amount
                else:
                    balance -= transaction_line.amount

                line = {
                    'transaction': transaction.id,
                    'description': transaction.description,
                    'transaction_date': transaction.transaction_date,
                    'sequence': transaction_line.sequence,
                    'transaction_type': transaction_line.transaction_type,
                    'ledger_account': transaction_line.ledger_account,
                    'amount': transaction_line.amount,
                    'balance': balance,
                }
                line_list.append(line)

        paginator = Paginator(line_list, 20)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            line_list = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            line_list = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            line_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_page)

        context = {'line_list': line_list, 'myFilter': myFilter, 'transactions': transactions,
                   'transaction_count': transaction_count, 'transaction_lines_count': transaction_lines_count,
                   'mylineFilter': mylineFilter, 'transaction_lines': transaction_lines, 'page': page}

        return context
```

**Filter.py**:

```
class lineFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    legder_account = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=tledger_account.objects.filter(
        company=request.user.current_company))

    class Meta:
        model = ttransaction_lines
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['transaction', 'sequence', 'quantity', 'posted', 'transaction_type', 'company', 'ledger_account']
```

This setup gives me an error:  `"name 'request' is not defined"`
The question is how do I get the request.user to the filter.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this(based on example from [documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-related-queryset-for-modelchoicefilter)):

```
def accounts(request):
    if request is None:
        return tledger_account.objects.none()
    return tledger_account.objects.filter(company=request.user.current_company))

class lineFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    legder_account = filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset= accounts)

# usage
my_filter = transactionFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=transactions, request=self.request)
```

FYI, class names should be `CamelCase` and method names should be `snake_case` as per [PEP-8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I however still have a problem. The request that is send to the filter is "None". although a user is logged in and linked to the current company. The ledger account choices are therefore empty. Do i need to change something on views.py as well?

Comment: Oops, my bad. Yes, you need to pass request as `request=self.request`, please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is working fine now. Also thanks for the reference to the style guide.